# SPI on F3Discovery

Tags: c, stm32, cortex-m

im trying to write SPI connection for the F3Disco and i have following problem:
When i try to use Std libraries it works, but only with registers not...
Settings:

```
void GyroSPIConf(){
RCC->AHBENR |= RCC_AHBENR_GPIOAEN;
RCC->AHBENR |= RCC_AHBENR_GPIOEEN;
RCC->APB2ENR |= RCC_APB2ENR_SPI1EN;
/* Set functions GPIO - SCK, MISO, MOSI */
GPIOA->MODER |= GPIO_MODER_MODER5_1 | GPIO_MODER_MODER6_1 | GPIO_MODER_MODER7_1;
GPIOA->OSPEEDR |= GPIO_OSPEEDER_OSPEEDR5 | GPIO_OSPEEDER_OSPEEDR6 | GPIO_OSPEEDER_OSPEEDR7;
GPIOA->AFR[0] |= GPIO_AFRL_AFRL5 | GPIO_AFRL_AFRL6 | GPIO_AFRL_AFRL7;

/* Set PE3 as CS - GPIO output */
GPIOE->MODER |= GPIO_MODER_MODER3_0;
GPIOE->OSPEEDR |= GPIO_OSPEEDER_OSPEEDR3;
GPIOE->ODR |= GPIO_ODR_3;

/* Set SPI MASTER 2,25 MHz; 8 bit */
SPI1->CR1 |= SPI_CR1_SSM | SPI_CR1_SSI | SPI_CR1_MSTR | SPI_CR1_BR_1;// | SPI_CR1_BR_0;
SPI1->CR2 |= SPI_CR2_FRXTH;

/* SPI */
SPI1->CR1 |= SPI_CR1_SPE;
GPIOE->BSRR = (1 << 3);
}
void IOInit(void)
{
    __GPIOE_CLK_ENABLE();
    GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStructure;

    GPIO_InitStructure.Pin =    GPIO_PIN_12 |                   // LD9  - Blue
                                GPIO_PIN_8  |                   // LD4  - Blue
                                GPIO_PIN_15 |                   // LD6  - Green
                                GPIO_PIN_14 |                   // LD8  - Orange
                                GPIO_PIN_13 |                   // LD10 - Red 
                                GPIO_PIN_10 |                   // LD5  - Orange
                                GPIO_PIN_11 |                   // LD7  - Green
                                GPIO_PIN_9;                     // LD3  - Red

    GPIO_InitStructure.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
    GPIO_InitStructure.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_HIGH;
    GPIO_InitStructure.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOE, &GPIO_InitStructure);

    __GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();                                       // Will be overwritten
}
```

Than main

```
int main(void)
{
    uint8_t Data[8];
    HAL_Init();
    IOInit();   
    GyroSPIConf();  
    GyroWriteByte(0x20, 0x0F);
    while (1){
        Data[0] = GyroReadByte(0x8f);
    }
}
```

Functions:

```
uint8_t GyroTransferByte(uint8_t val) {
    volatile uint8_t * const ptr = (volatile uint8_t *)&SPI1->DR;
    while (!(SPI1->SR & SPI_SR_TXE)) {};
    *ptr = val;
    while (!(SPI1->SR & SPI_SR_RXNE)) {};
    return *ptr;
}

void GyroWriteByte(uint8_t addr, uint8_t val) {
    uint8_t d;
    GPIOE->BSRR = (1 << 19);
    d = GyroTransferByte(addr);
    d = GyroTransferByte(val);
    GPIOE->BSRR = (1 << 3);
}

uint8_t GyroReadByte(uint8_t addr) {
    GPIOE->BSRR = (1 << 19);
    GPIOE->BSRR = (1 << 24);
    volatile uint8_t val;
    //addr |= R_BIT;
    val = GyroTransferByte(addr);
    val = GyroTransferByte(DUMMY_BYTE);
    GPIOE->BSRR = (1 << 3);
    GPIOE->BSRR = (1 << 8); 
    return val;
}
```

Any idea why i have always 0x00 in Data?

After changing:

```
uint8_t GyroReadByte(uint8_t addr) {
    GPIOE->BSRR = (1 << 19);
    GPIOE->BSRR = (1 << 24);
    volatile uint8_t val;
    //addr |= R_BIT;
    GyroSendByte(addr); //val = GyroTransferByte(addr);
    val = GyroTransferByte(DUMMY);
    GPIOE->BSRR = (1 << 3);
    GPIOE->BSRR = (1 << 8); 
    return val;
}
void GyroSendByte(uint8_t data) {
    GPIOE->BSRR = (1 << 19);
    volatile uint8_t * const ptr = (volatile uint8_t *)&SPI1->DR;
    while (!(SPI1->SR & SPI_SR_TXE)) {}
    ;
    *ptr = data;
    GPIOE->BSRR = (1 << 3);
}
```

I get 0xff (the real value is 0xD4)

EDIT:
After the change i get in first run: FF
After second run: DF
After third run: D4 -Correct value 
And then for the rest runs FF ...

So propably do i need to clear the buffer?

Comment: From your question I cannot tell the code you've written yourself (the stuff that doesn't work) from the library code that does. Can you please edit your question to include all relevant information? E.g. what does `IOInit()` do etc.

Comment: Hi, i have edited it, so that it is the complete code, the one writen on std was another project, but it works and so i know that the configuration values are for both project the same...

Comment: Just an idea: The discovery boards have jumpers that enable/disable hardware features. Are you testing the "working" code on same hardware setting as it has been verified on previously?

Comment: Yes, for both projects i use the same IDE, Compiler and Board

Comment: Do you have access to an oscilloscope?

Comment: Not today, i borrowed my osci to a friend... Hopefully tommorow :/

Comment: One thing I notice, you're only or'ing in config bits, some of white are multiple bits wide. If you don't clear the bits before or'ing in your new bits, then the result may not have the value you're after in the field. Notably, I believe AFR defaults to 1's for all IO (not 100% on this, but I think 1 is GPIO and default). I'd double check that you're actually getting the config you intended.

Comment: @rjp I agree with your suggestion to doublecheck that the registers are set to the same values as when using the working code.